# eigenvalues of the product of a unitary with a diagonal

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis

In $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, suppose  $U$ and $D$ are a  unitary and an invertible diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\{e^{i\theta_1},\cdots,e^{i\theta_n}\}$ and $\{e^{i\eta_1},\cdots,e^{i\eta_n}\}$ respectively.

Q. What information are obtained for the eigenvalues $\{e^{i\zeta_1},\cdots e^{i\zeta_n}\}$  of $UD$ with respect to $\theta_i's$ and $\eta_i's$?

Comment: $\sum_i \zeta_i=\sum_{i}(\theta_i+\eta_i)$ --- no other relationship without knowledge of the eigenvectors of $U$.

Comment: Do you mean that eigenvalues of $UD$ have absolute values 1?

Comment: @FedorPetrov : both $U$ and $D$ are unitary (for real $\theta_i$ and $\eta_i$), so their product is unitary and the eigenvalues have absolute value 1 --- did I miss something?

Comment: I read it so that $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal

Comment: @FedorPetrov --- please correct me if I'm wrong, the relation $\sum_i \zeta_i=\sum_{i}(\theta_i+\eta_i)$ between the eigenvalues $e^{i\zeta_k},e^{i\theta_k},e^{i\eta_k}$ of $UD,U,D$ is just equating determinants; if $D$ is not unitary it would mean that the $\eta_k$'s are not real, which is fine, the relation still holds, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, it holds of course (modulo $2\pi$, but the guys theirselves are defined modulo $2\pi$)

Comment: This is the same as just multiplying two general unitary matrices since one can always choose a basis that diagonalizes one of them.

Comment: There's more one can say, see here for example: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087408817038?journalCode=glma20